# Value To Pass Lags on one UIAction Button

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with 6 buttons that all segue to another view controller with a table view. Depending on the button that pressed, different values are passed to the view controller with a table view:

```
@IBAction func englishButton(_ sender: Any) {
    valueToPass = "English"
}


@IBAction func scienceButton(_ sender: Any) {
    valueToPass = "Science"
}

@IBAction func historyButton(_ sender: Any) {
    valueToPass = "History"
}


@IBAction func foriegnLanguageButton(_ sender: Any) {
    valueToPass = "Foriegn Language"
}


@IBAction func mathButton(_ sender: Any) {
    valueToPass = "Math"
}


@IBAction func otherSubjectsButton(_ sender: Any) {
    valueToPass = "Other Subjects"
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

    if (segue.identifier == "english") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! BuyMenuController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "science") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! BuyMenuController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "history") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! BuyMenuController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "foriegnLanguage") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! BuyMenuController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "math") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! BuyMenuController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
    if (segue.identifier == "otherSubjects") {
        // initialize new view controller and cast it as your view controller
        let viewController = segue.destination as! BuyMenuController
        // your new view controller should have property that will store passed value
        viewController.passedValue = valueToPass
    }
}
```

The issue here is that whenever I press the scienceButton, the value that's passed to the next view controller is either nil or the value that was passed before it. When clicked again, the value that passed is "science" like its suppose to. And this only happens to that one button, Any ideas why is this happening? (I've tried setting it up with an if-else if structure too).

Comment: Are to triggering the segue with an action on the button in Interface Builder?  If so don't. The segue may trigger before the IBAction code runs. You should Se `performSegueWithIdentifier` in your IBAction after you have set the value to pass. You will need to link the segue from your view controller object in Interface Buillder and give it an identifier

Comment: Worked! Put submit this as an answer so i can mark it as so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't combine `@IBAction` methods with segues linked directly to actions in Interface Builder as the segue may be performed before the function is executed.

You should link the segue to the view controller object and perform it programatically in your `@IBAction` function after you have set your variables.